# Updated Ruby gems and broke the whole site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was trying to install a website on a linux box and i was getting gems errors and google told me to update gems.  So I did.. Comes to find out the site was their production and its now down.  I ran the following command and now this happens.

```
sudo gem update --system
```

I have tried: `gem update --system 1.8.25`

And got the following error:

```
 Updating rubygems-update
    Fetching: rubygems-update-1.8.25.gem (100%)
    Successfully installed rubygems-update-1.8.25
    Parsing documentation for rubygems-update-1.8.25
    file 'hide_lib_for_update' not found
    file 'History.txt' not found
    file 'LICENSE.txt' not found
    file 'MIT.txt' not found
    file 'Manifest.txt' not found
    file 'README.rdoc' not found
    file 'UPGRADING.rdoc' not found
    file 'hide_lib_for_update/note.txt' not found
    ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
        undefined method `store' for #<RDoc::RDoc:0x7fe8216341e0>
```

Below is the full error message on the screen.  I am really new to rails and ruby.

```
Error message:
no such file to load -- rubygems/source_index (MissingSourceFile)
Exception class:
PhusionPassenger::UnknownError
Application root:


0   /usr/lib64/rubyee/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb 982 in `_deprecated_source_index'
1   /usr/lib64/rubyee/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/deprecate.rb   39  in `skip_during'
2   /usr/lib64/rubyee/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb 981 in `_deprecated_source_index'
3   /usr/lib64/rubyee/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/deprecate.rb   63  in `send'
4   /usr/lib64/rubyee/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/deprecate.rb   63  in `source_index'
5   /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb  21  in `add_frozen_gem_path'
6   /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/initializer.rb   298 in `add_gem_load_paths'
7   /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/initializer.rb   132 in `process'
8   /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/initializer.rb   113 in `send'
9   /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/initializer.rb   113 in `run'
11  /usr/lib64/rubyee/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb  36  in `gem_original_require'
12  /usr/lib64/rubyee/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb  36  in `require'
13  /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb   222 in `preload_application'
14  /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb   181 in `initialize_server'
15  /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb   572 in `report_app_init_status'
16  /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb   174 in `initialize_server'
17  /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb 204 in `start_synchronously'
18  /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb 180 in `start'
19  /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb   149 in `start'
20  /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb   219 in `spawn_rails_application'
21  /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb  132 in `lookup_or_add'
22  /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb   214 in `spawn_rails_application'
23  /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb  82  in `synchronize'
24  /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb  79  in `synchronize'
25  /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb   213 in `spawn_rails_application'
26  /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb   132 in `spawn_application'
27  /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb   275 in `handle_spawn_application'
28  /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb 357 in `__send__'
29  /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb 357 in `server_main_loop'
30  /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb 206 in `start_synchronously'
31  /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.11/helper-scripts/passenger-spawn-server    99
```

Comment: According to the version number it looks like that server wasn't updated in the last 5 years. Almost all version in the stacktrace are unmaintained and unsupported for years now. Does the application at least have a Gemfile with version numbers?

Comment: You can try to run `gem update --system 1.8.25 --no-rdoc --no-ri` and see if that completes the downgrade.

Comment: @Casper THANK YOU! post an answer and i will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your gem downgrade process is failing because it can't generate the documentation (probably an RDoc version problem).

You can try to run the downgrade without generating the docs like this:

```
gem update --system 1.8.25 --no-rdoc --no-ri
```

See if that helps complete the downgrade...

Answer (score 0):

When you update the system gems, the versions bump. Your project is loading some of the new versions, and something's not working.

You should first try to cd into your app and run `bundle` (or `sudo bundle`, if you have it set up this way). This will use your `Gemfile.lock` to find the correct versions to install.

If things still aren't working, try and pinpoint which gem is failing and specify a working version in the Gemfile. Something like `gem 'mygem', '~> 1.0.0'` where the version is known to be working. Then run `bundle` or `sudo bundle` to update.

You should try and keep your production machine in parity with your local environment. The same Ruby version should be used and ideally a similar architecture. That way the same gems will be installed both places and you can debug locally.

I'd also heard the recommendation to isolate your project's gems from your system's. You could use `rbenv` or `RVM` to do this. Then you'd no longer use `sudo` to install gems. Thought I'm not sure if that'd fix anything here.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. i believe the gems isnt downgrading. its 
bluetube@Megatron ~ $ gem -v
2.6.4

Comment: after trying to down grade it gem update --system 1.8.25